# Excel Spreadsheet not giving same answer as C# program

Tags: c#, excel, double-precision, integer-division

I have trouble with the following code. It is not giving the same answer in excel as C# and I'm sure the excel answer is correct. I have already tried to change integer values to double by adding a decimal point. Please advise.

the excel version

```
=((1+BZ21)*BX21*CG21*(B21*1))-(0.5*BZ21*BX21*CG21*((C21*0)+(0*D21)))
```

the c# version

```
voltageVector[rows, 5] = ((1.0 + ki) * Rp * c * (ma * 1.0)) - (0.5 * ki * Rp * c * ((mb * 0.0 )+ (mc * 0.0)));
```

The constants ki, Rp, c and ma are all double precision values.

```
ki = 0.69999999999999907;
Rp = 0.0469486290322602;
c = 60.0
ma = 2.0;
mb = 1.0;
mc = 1.0;
```

The C# answer is

```
9.5775203225810763
```

The excel answer is `9.56760000000433`

Comment: What values are you getting in each?

Comment: Whats this point of this part `(0.5 * ki * Rp * c * ((mb * 0.0 )+ (mc * 0.0)))`? It will always give 0 wont it?

Comment: Probably the same purpose as `ma * 1.0`.  Although it won't be exactly `0` or `ma` thanks to double precision.

Comment: If I recall it right Excel works with decimals (128 bits) instead of doubles (64 bits)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something's funny in your Excel spreadsheet.  When I tried this, I get the same answer in both C# and Excel.  I believe the correct answer is 9.577520323.  Here's a screenshot of my Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: Same here -  my Excel number matches the posted C# output.

Comment: Yeah!! I found out the problem, it was to do with the c# fetching a wrong value for Rp!!!!. Thanks so much for the help though!